# Why do Canon 6d raw photos have a red tint across the entire image in Windows preview?

Tags: canon, raw, windows, picasa, canon-6d

When I try to preview RAW Canon 6D photos in my several Windows 7 and Windows xp laptops, most photos have a red "shadow" across the whole picture. How to solve this problem? On Mac, photos looks ok.

This is a screenshot below. For the first two seconds the image looks normal when it appears on the screen, and then red shadow comes.
[image: bad raw]

Answer (score 7):

You are using Picasa.

If you simply type in "Picasa Canon 6D" into Google, you will see that many other users have this problem.

Why are you having this problem? Because **Picasa does not support the Canon 6D RAW files**.

What can you do to fix this? Use the Adobe DNG Converter before opening up the files in Picasa. You could use something besides Picasa like the Canon software that came with your camera - DPP or Adobe Lightroom. You also could shoot in JPEG instead of RAW.

Comment: It's interesting, you can even see the border of masked pixels that are part of the sensor, and read into the .CR2, but not part of the image once it has been properly demosaiced. That's a real giveaway when a Canon RAW image is not being processed properly.

Answer (score 2):

Try to install [Microsoft Camera Codec Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26829) for Windows 7.

For XP you can try [Microsoft RAW Image Thumbnailer and Viewer for Windows XP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8802) or if this doesn't work the commercial software [FastPictureViewer Codec Pack](http://www.fastpictureviewer.com/codecs/).

Comment: I have installed Microsoft Camera Codec Pack. Now works fine with windows viewer, but Picasa viewer still have red fog.

Comment: You didn't say anything about picasa in your initial post. Perhaps http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1017/how-does-picasa-process-raw-photos is interesting for you.

Comment: @dpollitt the screenshot was uploaded later..you see it in the revisions http://photo.stackexchange.com/posts/43553/revisions

Comment: @redreggae - Good point!

Answer (score 0):

Good news after a long wait...

Google just released a Picasa update (3.9.137.69) on Dec 12, 2013 which includes RAW support for newer cameras.

Release notes here: https://support.google.com/picasa/answer/53209

I have the 6D and that darn pink overlay is gone. Yay!

To update in Picasa... click Help > Check for updates.